# count the number of employees in certain department in sql

Tags: sql

I have a problem about writing a SQL query on counting the number of employees.

Here is the question: There are 2 tables,

`T1`, the attributes are `E_ID(primary key), E_Name, DpartmentID;`

`T2`, `DepartmentID(primary key), DepartmentName`

Mow i want to count the number of employees in technology department, should i write as below?

```
SELECT COUNT(E_T1.ID)
FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.DepartmentID = T2.DepartmentID
WHERE T2.DepartmentName = 'Technology'
```

I was asked this question during an interview, but the interviewee said I missed something... can anyone help me with it? thanks!

Comment: Maybe a typo. Table t1 has column e_id and not id.

Comment: wumpz is right, looks good in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f4be/1/0)

Comment: Sorry guys for my typo...I've fixed it. But it's not the typo thing...

Comment: I thought the only modification is to add Group By  but why's that...

Comment: The only thing (super minor) is that by specifying a Column in your Count, you exclude any rows where that column is null.  But also what SQL server?

Comment: No information for the server actually. The interviewee reminded me that count is an aggregate function at that time. But I still don't get it...

Answer (score 1):

Your query makes some assumptions:

- that the department table is unique on name.
- that all departments has employees assigned to them.

I would write that query as

```
select dept.DepartmentId as department_id ,
       sum(case when emp.E_ID is not null then 1 else 0 end) as employee_count ,
from      T2 dept
left join T1 emp  on emp.DepartmentId = dept.DepartmentId
where dept.DepartmentName = 'Technology'
group by t2.DepartmentId
```

- You'll notice that I've inverted the join order to emphasize the fact that you're producing summary information about the department.
- We do a left [outer] join from the department table to the employee table. This guarantees we get at least one row for every department, even if there are no employees assigned to it.
- Then we use `sum()` with a *discriminant function to product the count.

Another approach you could take might be

You should try

```
select dept.DepartmentId as department_id ,
       ( select count(*)
         from T1 emp
         where emp.DepartmentId = dept.DepartmentId
       ) as employee_count
from      T2 dept
where dept.DepartmentName = 'Technology'
group by dept.DepartmentId
```

Whether this gets a better execution plan than my first solution is dependent on all sorts of factors in your database. The only way to tell would be to check the execution plan against production-like data.

Where this query is simpler, more (or less) elegant than my first solution is subjective. This solution does contain a correlated subquery which [theoretically] means that the subquery has to be executed once for every row in the outer result set — which is presumably 1, so it should be wash from an execution plan perspective. Of course, any decent query optimizer out to be able to refactor it into a join anyway ... but I digress.